# How to create a std::set from the symmetric difference of two sets

Tags: c++, stl, set

I Have two sets of strings.

```
set<string> A;
set<string> B;
```

I will insert some elements into both the sets and some of the elements that I insert into them are common elements.

I can basically get the elements

- Present in A and not in B
- Present in B and not in A

using

```
std::set_difference
```

I can also get the common elements in both the sets by

using

```
std::set_intersection
```

How can I get the elements which and present *only in A* and *only in B* and put them in a different set?

Total idea is creating a set which will not have the common elements but all the elements in both the sets.

In mathematical language:

```
(A(UNION)B)-(A(intersection)B)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [`std::set_symmetric_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference)? It seems to fit what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [set_symmetric_difference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference/)